# Activate conda environment from batch file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've installed Anaconda 1.9.12 and everything works fine for designing python scripts and executing them. Now that I have my code ready, I want to allow for an external program to call `python myCode.py myInputFile.dat` but this fails to activate the environment and my import commands fail. I can activate the environment manually by using the `Activate.bat` file the Anaconda provides but when I put this into a batch file, the command prompt exists after I called `Activate.bat` and never gets to `python.exe`

Here is my batch file

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe myCode.py myInputFile.dat
```

The first line runs and then the command window closes before it gets to the next line. I really want this thing to run automatically without me having to open a command window, activate the environment and then call the python routine.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the `conda.exe` is on Windows, but one can use `conda.exe run` to execute commands within environments without having to activate them in a shell session. For example, you should be able to do something like

```batch
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe run -n base python myCode.py myInputFile.dat
```

If you require interactivity, you’ll also need either (or both) the flags `--live-stream` or `--no-capture-output`.

Comment: That works but it doesn't allow for any user input. When I have input("Press a key") it throws an EOF error. can I call Conda.exe in a shell interactive environment?

Comment: Thanks @merv, that did the trick. I do note however that I had too run conda update to allow those flags